# PHP Login System without MySQL

Tags: php, authentication

So, I'm trying to set up a login script without the usage of MySQL because I don't have any experience with it at all I need to wait one year until I can sign up for a course at our school.

My thoughts of approaching this:

The user needs to login with a username and a invitation key. I'd like to have a .txt (I know that's insecure as hell but whatever) where both the username and invitation key of an accepted person are stored. The PHP scripts compares the sent credentials with the ones stored in the .txt. If it matches, you're logged in, if not, then it gets aborted.

So, how can I read data from a .txt and how could I format the .txt so my script can differ between username and invitation key?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['auth']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    session_start();

    $usr=$_POST['user'];
    $invkey=$_POST['key'];

    function authenticate($usr, $invkey){

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: I know this would be very insecure, so if you're bored you could give me tips how I could secure it. :)

Comment: To be secure use .htaccess, and reading from a text file is a very basic thing try to search for it on the internet.

Comment: I would recommend a properly formatted CSV file to store this stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can keep usernames and keys in one string, one user per line in a txt file.

```
user1|user1_inv_key
user2|user2_inv_key
...
```

So you can use [fgets()](http://php.net/fgets) and [explode()](http://php.net/explode)

Your code should look like this :

```
if(isset($_POST['auth']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    session_start();

    $usr=$_POST['user'];
    $invkey=$_POST['key'];

    function authenticate($usr, $invkey){
        $fh = fopen('auth.txt', 'r');
        if ($handle) {
          while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            // Exploding the line, using | as separator.
            $info = explode($line, '|');
            $username = $info[0];
            $key = $info[1];
            if($usr == $username && $key == $invkey) return true;
          }
        } else {
         // error opening the file.
        }
        // Return false because something went wrong or data wasn't correct.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a normal csv file like

```
user1,key1
user2,key2
```

and then use the str_getcsv function to parse it.

See http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-getcsv.php for more documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like

```
$txt_file    = file_get_contents('path/to/file.txt');
```

Then you could explode $txt_file based on a delimiter for each user, or a new line or something. Then, you could add a new user to your file with something like

```
file_put_contents("path/to/file.txt", $user_string, FILE_APPEND);
```

To secure it, you could save the password for the user as the product of a one way hash, like md5.

```
$salt = 'whatever you want';
$securish_pw = md5($password.$salt);
```

Then store that. Then, someone logs in, you find their line in the txt file, put their compared password through the same md5 function and if they are the same, then you log them in. This way, you don't store a plain text password.

All said, you should just learn a bit about how to use a database. It's pretty simple if you use PHP's PDO library and there's a million and one tutorials out there explaining how to do exactly what you're trying to accomplish.